# How to extend an xml-schema from another xml-schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xml document that looks something like below (resources.xml), with a corresponding xml-schema (resources.xsd). This xml document is manually maintained (i.e adding/removing/editing resource elements). In total there are maybe 500-1000 resource elements. Each resource can be of either variantX or variantY (in "real life", there are a few more variants).

I would like to split up the xml document into several xml documents. One xml document for each variant (X and Y in this case), with a corresponding new xml-schemas. The xml schemas for each variant, should extend the original schema and only add a "hardcoded" (fixed?) value for it's "variant" attribute.

Reason: To avoid repeating the "variant" attribute within each resource element.

Is this possible? What would the xml-schemas for each variant look like? What changes needs to be done in resources.xsd?

Any other suggestions are also welcomed :)

### resources.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resources.xsd">
        <resource name="res00" variant="X" >
            <property name="propA" value="..." />
            <property name="propB" value="..." />
        </resource>
        <resource name="res01" variant="X" >
            <property name="propA" value="..." />
            <property name="propB" value="..." />
        </resource>
        <resource name="res02" variant="Y" >
            <property name="propA" value="..." />
            <property name="propB" value="..." />
        </resource>
        <resource name="res03" variant="Y" >
            <property name="propA" value="..." />
            <property name="propB" value="..." />
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

### resources.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:rb="http://example.org/resourcebase">

    <xs:complexType name="property">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="resource">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="property" type="property" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="variant" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="resources">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="resource" type="resource" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here's how I picture this. One xml document for variant=X, which referrers to resourcesX.xsd. No need to add the "variant" attribute, as it is added by the referred resourcesX.xsd.

### resourcesX.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resourceX.xsd">
        <resource name="res00" >
            <property name="propA" value="..." />
            <property name="propB" value="..." />
        </resource>
        <resource name="res01" >
            <property name="propA" value="..." />
            <property name="propB" value="..." />
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Another xml document for variant=Y, which referrers to resourcesY.xsd. No need to add the "variant" attribute, as it is added by the referred resourcesY.xsd.

### resourcesY.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resourceY.xsd">
        <resource name="res02" >
            <property name="propA" value="..." />
            <property name="propB" value="..." />
        </resource>
        <resource name="res03" >
            <property name="propA" value="..." />
            <property name="propB" value="..." />
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Can resourceX.xsd and resourceY.xsd extend the resources.xsd? If so, what would they look like? any changes needed to be made in resources.xsd?

Thanks!
/Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your goal is to only have resources of a single variant in a particular file, in that case, instead of removing the `variant` attribute, would it make sense to move it to the root `resources` type? This would allow the document structure to retain the information about which variant is being represented, but also ensure that all of the `resource` elements in a particular file are associated with a particular variant. Something like:

### resources.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="property">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="resource">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="property" type="property" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="resources">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="resource" type="resource" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="variant" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and instance document:

### resourceX.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resources.xsd"
        variant="X">
    <resource name="res00" >
        <property name="propA" value="..." />
        <property name="propB" value="..." />
    </resource>
    <resource name="res01" >
        <property name="propA" value="..." />
        <property name="propB" value="..." />
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

To split this into multiple schema files, you'll first need to modify your base schema to include only the types and elements that will be shared, and will need to refine those elements to allow extension (or restriction in your derived schemas). In your case, it looks like the `property` type will be reused and the `resource` type will be restricted, so the base schema would look something like:

### resources.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="property">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="resource">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="property" type="property" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="variant" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Note in resource, the `variant` attribute no longer is `use="required"`, since your goal is that you will not want that to be required in your instance documents.

For the 'X' variant of the schema, you'll need to include the `resources.xsd` schema, and will need to define your restricted `resourceX` element and the containing `resources` element.

### resourceX.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="resources.xsd"/>

    <xs:complexType name="resourceX">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="resource">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="property" type="property" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="variant" type="xs:string" fixed="X"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="resources">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="resource" type="resourceX" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

The `xs:include` statement will include your previously defined schema. The new types `resourceX` defines your restriction on the `resource` element, and associates the fixed value `X` with `variant`. Finally the `resources` element is redefined to be a collection of elements of type `resourceX` instead of `resource`.

`resourceY.xsd` would be defined in a similar manner to `resourceX.xsd`.

Comment: thanks. I later realized the xml-parser I use (SimpleXml) did not read the xsd... :-/