# XML Schema Extension with Visual Studio Code

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, xsd

I am currently working on a project, where I have a base XML Schema that I have to extend. I tried following the solutions of https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp and [How to extend an xml-schema from another xml-schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776894/how-to-extend-an-xml-schema-from-another-xml-schema).

I am using XML Tools 2.3.2 on Visual Studio Code, that work as expected when validating xml to xsd. However, when I try to extend the schema like depicted below:

node.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="node" type="nodeType"></xs:element>
...
</xs:schema>
```

nodeextenstion.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:include schemaLocation="node.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Visual Studio Code throws me this error:

[image: Visual Studio Code XSD Extension Error]

Has anybody experienced this behaviour and may help me out.

Appreciate every hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `schemaLocation` is not part of the current "xmlns", it cannot be recognized.

"Please try":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <xs:include schemaLocation="node.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

... add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` in the node hierarchy (above), where `schemaLocation` is used.

Alternatively:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <xs:include xsi:schemaLocation="node.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

..introduce `prefix` for "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" & use it as `prefix:schemaLocation`.

---

see also: [XML Schema Validation : Cannot find the declaration of element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15642046/592355)